# Not getting logged in to presashop website after clicking on login with facebook button

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-login, prestashop-1.6

Newbie in PrestaShop.

I am using PrestaShop version 1.6.1.6.

I have implemented login with facebook functionality on my site.

I have downloaded PrestaShop FaceBook Connect module from https://www.modulebazaar.com/prestashop-facebook-connect.html

when I click on login with facebook button it ask me user-details once I logged in and granting permissions it redirects back to my website and not login into prestashop website.

I have configured presashop website into my localhost.

below are the facebook application settings
[image]

I have checked in admin panel but not even customer has created.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should ask the creators of that plugin.

Comment: Hi @luschn I have already asked the author of the plugin but not getting any response.

Comment: you have to wait then. stackoverflow is for developers only. you would have to be a lot more specific than "it does not work" ;) - do some debugging first. and check if the app is really authorized correctly (you can see that in your facebook.com settings)

Comment: "it does not work" has said because the functionality works based on plugin     .